# How to parse values returned by getDate() in java?

Tags: java, android, parsing, getdate

I have created a web service which returns the date of an event which is initially captured by the getDate() function. I want the date returned by this function (something along this format : 2013-05-17 14:52:00.943) to be parsed and shown to the user in the DD-MM-YYYY format.

Any suggestions? I haven't found any solution along this direction yet.

Comment: is this getDate php function?

Comment: Nope its an SQL function.

Comment: there are SimpleDateFormat to change date formate see

Comment: I dont see your link @AnkitMakwana.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: you want to change in Android right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this code and it's work fine for me,Please Try my code below: Please upvote to Tarun also coz he gave almost right answer.just he did mistake that he passes cal.getTime() method instead of pDate

> String formatDate = p.format(pDate);

and second mistake in format like"DD-MM-YYYY" but actual format is:

> "dd-MM-yyyy" not "DD-MM-YYYY"

I have done changes in it and modify it.

```
String dateStr = "2013-05-16 14:52:00.943"; 

SimpleDateFormat c = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"); // your web service format
Date pDate = c.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // your required format

String formatDate = p.format(pDate); // convert it in your required format
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // Day format as you want EEE for like "Sat" and EEEE for like "Saturday"
String Day = formatter.format(pDate); // This will give you a day as your selected format

System.out.println("Date & Day>>>"+formatDate+" "+Day);
```

// For GMT format your format should be like this: "2013-05-16 14:52:00.943 GMT+05:30"

```
// Give it to me in GMT time.
c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));
System.out.println("GMT time: " + c.format(pDate));
```

Output:

```
Date & Day>>>16-05-2013 Thursday
GMT time: 2013-05-16 02:52:00.943 Greenwich Mean Time
```

**Joda time:**

you can download 2.0 jar file of joda time from [here:](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.0)

```
DateTimeFormatter jodaFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime jodaParsed = jodaFormatter
                .parseDateTime("2013-05-17T16:27:34.9+05:30");
Date date2 = jodaParsed.toDate();
System.out.println("Date & Day:" + jodaParsed.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + jodaParsed.getMonthOfYear() + "-" + jodaParsed.getYear() + " " + jodaParsed.getHourOfDay() + ":" + jodaParsed.getMinuteOfHour()+" "+jodaParsed.dayOfWeek().getAsText());
```

output:

```
Date & Day:17-5-2013 16:27 Friday
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Okay it gives the following error:

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2013-05-17T16:27:34.9+05:30" (at offset 10).

Comment: Im guessing it has something to do with the semicolon that seperates my time zone and time. Gah! Help. :|

Comment: It should be like "2013-05-17T16:27:34.9+0530"

Comment: Using string functions will just make it messier, isn't there some way around this?

Comment: @GarimaTiwari check my updated answer I have updated my answer for the GMT time but format should be like that format I have wrote in my answer. And if you don't change then try Tarun updated answer. you can ask another question for GMT time if required.

Comment: Im using a predefined function so obviously I cant tweak the format. Will try what you suggested.

Comment: check my edited answer for the joda time. and Thank you once again to Tarun for the joda time answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
String dateStr = "2013-05-17 14:52:00.943"; 

SimpleDateFormat c = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"); 
Date pDate = c.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat p = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 

String formatDate = p.format(pDate);
```

You can use Joda Time if you have colon in time offset.

```
DateTimeFormatter jodaFormatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
DateTime jodaParsed = jodaFormatter.parseDateTime("2013-05-17T16:27:34.9+05:30"); 
Date date = jodaParsed.toDate();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(date); 
c.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

More info about joda can be found [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html).

Comment: But I wont get the day along with the date will I?

Comment: `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); c.setTime(date); c.get(Calendar.DATE)); ` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: upvote for your GMT answer.It is right for the new format given by @GarimaTiwari.

Comment: I looked up whatever format the getDate() function returns and there is no T in it, i wonder whats causing this.

Comment: @GarimaTiwari you just have to call DateTime jodaParsed = jodaFormatter.parseDateTime("your date"); It will give you the parsed date and time which you can use to create date object.

Comment: Ok let me try and get back to you, cant thank you enough for your prompt replies and efforts!

Comment: I suggest you to go through the joda time user guide. [joda time user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

Comment: Its not recognizing either the "DateTime" or the "jodaFormatter" phrases, not suggesting any imports either.

Comment: Get the library and add in in your project. https://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/

Answer (score 2):

Use a SimpleDateFormat to parse the date and then print it out with a SimpleDateFormat withe the desired format.

Example:

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = format1.parse("05/18/2013");
System.out.println(format2.format(date));
```

Output:

11-05-2013

Edit:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(specific_date);
int dayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

String dayOfMonthStr = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
```

Comment: Hello again, I didn't quite completely understand the above code you gave but is there any way I can display the day along with the date using the date format I've mentioned in my question?

Comment: day means in which sense??

Comment: Like today, 18-05-2013 along with Saturday.

Comment: Hey you should do like this go get your result "MM/dd/yyyy EEEE" please go through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @Segi, all my chatrooms are blocked in office! Sorry :P